# How to convert field from ISODate to milliseconds with mongodb's aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, type-conversion, aggregation-framework

How can I convert ISODate to long milliseconds with aggregation framework?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$toLong`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) to convert the date to milliseconds since epoch in 4.0 mongo version.

```
db.colname.aggregate( {
   $addFields: {
      toMillis: { $toLong: "$datefieldname" }
   }
})
```